# Create a map showing all town locations

Tags: apex, visualforce, api, google-map

I have a custom object on SalesForce called clients. This object contains address line 1, town and postcode fields. I am looking for a way to show all the towns on one map as we would like to be able to see where all our clients are located across the country.

How would this be possible?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var map;
    var elevator;
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 1,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas')[0], myOptions);

    var addresses = ['Norway', 'Africa', 'Asia','North America','South America'];

    for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {
        $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addresses[x]+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
            var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map
            });

        });
    }

});
```

here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P2QhE/)

Comment: Sorry would this be a new visual force page or where would i insert this code? Also sorry you have the locations set, how would i auto populate al the town fields for all clients?

Comment: add this code into your VF page and address in the addresses array.

Answer (score 1):

Get the list of City in an array and pass it to Map.

Following code displays billingCountry of all accounts in the ORG.

```
 <apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accounts" docType="html-5.0" >
<apex:pageBlock >
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(document).ready(function() {

  var myOptions = {

    zoom: 1,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.terrain,
    mapTypeControl: true
  }

  var map;
  var marker;

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = new Array();
    <apex:repeat value="{!accounts}" var="addresss">
        if("{!addresss.BillingCountry}" != ""){
        address.push("{!addresss.BillingCountry}");

        }
    </apex:repeat>

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: ""
  });
 for (var x = 0; x < address.length; x++) {

 console.log(address[x]);
  geocoder.geocode( { address: address[x]}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length) {
      if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {

        //create map
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

        //center map
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

        //create marker
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map,
            title: "Nothing"
        });

        //add listeners
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
          map.setCenter(marker.getPosition()); 
        });

      }

    } else {
      $('#map').css({'height' : '15px'});
      $('#map').html("Oops! {!Account.Name}'s address could not be found, please make sure the address is correct.");
      resizeIframe();
    }
  })};

  function resizeIframe() {
    var me = window.name;
    if (me) {
      var iframes = parent.document.getElementsByName(me);
      if (iframes && iframes.length == 1) {
        height = document.body.offsetHeight;
        iframes[0].style.height = height + "px";
      }
    }
  }

});
</script>

<style>
#map {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:normal !important;
  height:500px;
  background:transparent;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div> 
</body> 
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, so if i have a client object with four address fields that make up the address such as "address line 1, address line 2, town, country, postcode" would this cost work for this situation and how could i make it show only the clients within the client object with status (which is a field) as "live"